# use multiprocessing or threading script python

Tags: python, multithreading

i want use multiprocessing or threading for this code
and I would like to control the threading example threads = (50)
if i chose 50 theards is opend 50 process
please help me 
this code :-

```
import subprocess
import csv

def ping(hostname):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1","-w","1000",hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    pingStatus = 'ok';

    for line in p.stdout:
        output = line.rstrip().decode('UTF-8')

        if (output.endswith('unreachable.')) :
            #No route from the local system. Packets sent were never put on the wire.
            pingStatus = 'unreacheable'
            break
        elif (output.startswith('Ping request could not find host')) :
            pingStatus = 'host_not_found'
            break
        if (output.startswith('Request timed out.')) :
            #No Echo Reply messages were received within the default time of 1 second.
            pingStatus = 'timed_out'
            break
        #end if
    #endFor

    return pingStatus
#endDef    


def printPingResult(hostname):
    statusOfPing = ping(hostname)

    if (statusOfPing == 'host_not_found') :
        writeToFile('!server-not-found.txt', hostname)
    elif (statusOfPing == 'unreacheable') :
       writeToFile('!unreachable.txt', hostname)
    elif (statusOfPing == 'timed_out') :
       writeToFile('!timed_out.txt', hostname)     
    elif (statusOfPing == 'ok') :
        writeToFile('!ok.txt', hostname)
    #endIf
#endPing


def writeToFile(filename, data) :
    with open(filename, 'a') as output:
        output.write(data + '\n')
    #endWith
#endDef    


'''
servers.txt example
   vm8558
   host2
   server873
   google.com
'''
file = open('hosts.txt')

try:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

    for item in reader:
        printPingResult(item[0].strip())
    #endFor
finally:
    file.close()
#endTry
```

i want use multiprocessing or threading for this code
and I would like to control the threading example threads = (50)
if i chose 50 theards is opend 50 process

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use pool object from `python` `multiprocessing` module.

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

> Pool object which offers a convenient means of parallelizing the execution of a function across multiple input values, distributing the input data across processes (data parallelism). The following example demonstrates the common practice of defining such functions in a module so that child processes can successfully import that module.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates multiprocessing for ping calls. 
Hope this helps.

**EDIT1**

```
**host.txt**
google.com
yahoo.com
microsoft.com
cnn.com
stackoverflow.com
github.com
```

**CODE**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import subprocess

def ping(hostname):
    return hostname, subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '3', '-w', '1000', hostname])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOSTFILE = 'server.txt'
    POOLCOUNT = 5
    #read host name file and load to list
    hostfile = open(HOSTFILE, 'r')
    hosts = [line.strip() for line in hostfile.readlines()]

    #Create pool    
    p = Pool(POOLCOUNT)

    #multiprocess and map ping function to host list
    print(p.map(ping, hosts))
```

**Result**

Status 1= sucess, 0 = failure

```
>>> 
[('google.com', 1), ('yahoo.com', 1), ('microsoft.com', 1), ('cnn.com', 1), ('stackoverflow.com', 1), ('github.com', 1)]
```

Comment: I cant edit your entire code. However I've modified answer so that you can read hosts from a text file into a list and use my answer. Similar way , result can be written to a any file as desired. Hope this helps.